# How to write configure select grants on tables after creation using dbt

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am new to dbt and I am trying to grant my tables select privileges after they have been created in my dbt code. So I am trying to create a SHARE between my snowflake account(my_SF) and another snowflake account(A_SF).
when I create dbt models and materialize them as tables, they are created successfully. My objective is to share these tables in my snowflake account with another snowflake account. I created a SHARE(123) manually, which is configured to use my database (abc)and Schema(def). The code below is used to grant access to a table (deposit) in the schema

```
Grant select on table abc.def.deposit to share 123
```

All these seem to work. and the table was easily shared with the second snowflake account I added to the SHARE.

The problem is, when I run dbt run, the tables are created in my Snowflake account but not visible to the second snowflake account because the SELECT GRANT to the table has been deleted.

Is there a way I can GRANT SELECT privilege to all tables after creation in DBT? I use dbt version 1.0

I tried to use this post-hook but it didnt work

```
post-hook: |
  {% set schema = abc.def%}
  {% set share = '123' %}

  {% for table in adapter.list_relations(schema=schema, materialized='table') %}
    GRANT SELECT ON {{ schema }}.{{ table }} TO SHARE {{ share }};
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you could check [dbt grants](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants) if they support shares. The last resort is [post-hook](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook) on the model to run arbitrary macro/SQL

Comment: will prefer to use Post-hook, pls can you provide some sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lee,
The Answer to your question no longer needs a post hook except you need soms fine-grained control or something complex outside what **dbt** provided as of July 2022.
You should do these grants with configs at either the project , subfolder or specific model level as documented here
[docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants)
This was addressed in the issue specific to **snowflake** here too [github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/issues/168](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/issues/168)

Hope this fixes your issue or at least helps others moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only tables and within the same schema, why don't you run something like the following:

```yaml
# your dbt_project.yml

models:
  +post-hook: "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <your_db>.<your_schema> TO SHARE <your_share>;"
```

You can have a look at the dbt docs [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook#grant-privileges-on-a-model), they have very similar use cases for granting permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Aleix, It seems straight forward but im getting some syntax error with share name. Im not sure if the share should be in quotes or not... I currently didnt add quote